# Search on file and rewrite (FS module NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm currently trying to update a content into my HTML file (writed by FS).
So, I wan't to update some content into this HTML file for update messages, by example.

So search the good div or the "a" with a custom value or other way to know the good message to change. And change the content into the HTML balise.

Sincerely. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*good div*" and "*good message*"? Also what is your question? Please show us your code and where you have trouble with it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

On my HTML page, I have Message content. I wan't to update the exactly message.

By example, edit div with id "messageId", with : "Test".
The content of the div will passed to "Message content" at "Test"

I didn't have tried anything because when I googled that, I don't have results.